# Bison: Reduce/reduce conflict on non-tokens

Tags: c, parsing, compiler-construction, bison

So I'm in the process of making a compiler for C-- and I'm currently making literal, variable and function tables.

And this rule is giving me a reduce/reduce conflict:

```
lval: ID { check_var(); }
| ID { check_var(); } LBRACK NUM RBRACK
| ID { check_var(); } LBRACK ID { check_var(); } RBRACK;
```

Error is the following:

```
parser.y: warning: 1 reduce/reduce conflict [-Wconflicts-rr]
parser.y:104.6-21: warning: rule useless in parser due to conflicts [-Wother]
 | ID { check_var(); } LBRACK ID { check_var(); } RBRACK;
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I have precendece rules to avoid reduce errors on tokens, but now it's pointing to a non token, so not sure what I'm supposed to do?

If it helps by any chance these are my precedence rules:

```
%token INPUT OUTPUT WRITE
%token  RETURN VOID IF ELSE WHILE ASSIGN SEMI COMMA
%token LPAREN RPAREN LBRACE RBRACE LBRACK RBRACK
%token NUM ID STRING INT
%left EQ NEQ GE LE GT LT
%left PLUS MINUS
%left TIMES OVER
```

Comment: Can you turn `ID { check_var(); }` into its own symbol? So then you have `lval: checked_id | checked_id LBRACK NUM RBRACK | checked_id LBRACK checked_id RBRACK;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bison does not check for whether two custom code blocks within your syntax are identical. So it treats your grammar as basically:

```
lval: ID action_1
    | ID action_2 LBRACK NUM RBRACK
    | ID action_3 LBRACK ID action_4 RBRACK
;
```

And Bison (by default) acts as an [LALR(1) parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LALR_parser), meaning it only looks ahead one token before making decisions. So when it sees that the top of the stack is an `ID` token and the look-ahead token is an `LBRACK` token, it can't decide whether it should execute `action_2` or `action_3`, not realizing it doesn't actually matter.

Solve this by using a subrule to combine the common thing that should happen when an `ID` is followed by an `LBRACK` (and also in other situations):

```
id_with_check: ID { check_var(); } ;

lval: id_with_check
    | id_with_check LBRACK NUM RBRACK
    | id_with_check LBRACK id_with_check RBRACK
;
```

Comment: That was amazingly precise and quick. I'm really left with no questions.
Thank you aschepler! 10/10